# Unable to find proxy server in firefox using browsermobproxy on saucelabs

Tags: java, firefox, proxy, saucelabs, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to run a test using browsermobproxy on saucelabs. But I am unable to run it. I am getting error as "Unable to find proxy server" in firefox browser.

I follow this for sauce labs:-

```
https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Sauce+Connect+Proxy+Configuration#SauceConnectProxyConfiguration-AutomaticProxyConfiguration
```

Browsermobproxy - https://github.com/lightbody

I have tried both browsermobproxy and browsermob-core-littleproxy. Both gives same error as above.

browsermob-proxy

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <!-- To use the legacy, Jetty-based implementation, 
             change the artifactId to browsermob-core -->
        <artifactId>browsermob-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

browsermob-core-littleproxy

net.lightbody.bmp
    
    browsermob-core-littleproxy
    2.1.0-beta-4
    test